# Extrair uma string após uma delimitador com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte retorno: `7100-1156` 
Como resultado gostaria de extrair sempre a segunda parte da string: `1156`.

O código de exemplo faz isso porém o problema é quando o valor da primeira parte da string tiver menos ou mais caracteres.

A ideia é extrair tudo que tiver após o `-` em qualquer situação.

```js
var codigo =  "7100-1156";
var resultado = codigo.substring(5, 15);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Por favor qual seria os outros exemplos, porque dar um `split` não vai resolver em todos os casos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode conseguir utilizando o método [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), que basicamente separa a string por um identificador, no caso aí o caractere **`-`** em um **array** aí é só pegar a parte que quer utilizar:

```js
var codigo =  "7100-1156";
var resultado = codigo.split('-');

console.log(resultado[1]);
```

Comment: LeAndrade muito obrigado, que Deus te abençoe!

Comment: Por nada André, amém!!

Answer (score 1):

Além de um `split`, você também poderia usar uma regex para pegar automaticamente a segunda parte da string:

```
'7100-1156'.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{4})/g, '\$2')
```

Nesse código, a string foi dividida em dois grupos, um antes do hífen e outro depois, cada qual contendo 4 dígitos. No `replace`, dizemos para substituir a expressão inteira apenas pelo seu segundo grupo - que corresponde ao desejado.